# Replace consecutive delimeters but not single delimeter occurence in unix

Tags: unix

I have an unix file whose delimeter is **#!**

I need to replace the delimeter '**#!**' to '**~**'

But I have '#' as data in some columns. I don't want to replace them.

I want to replace only # and ! together. I don't want to replace when either of them occurs single(only # or only !).

Please help me with a unix command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command to do replacements.

For example, if your file was data.txt:

```
sed 's/#!/~/g' data.txt > data_replaced.txt
```

IF you want to edit the file inplace, you can use this:

```
sed -i 's/#!/~/g' data.txt
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanq so much !!! It worked.. I did not know this inplace edition. Thanks